# webdrivermanager pip3 not found

Tags: python, pip, robotframework

I am trying to run robot-framework, for that I need webdriver in ubuntu-19.
I have installed :

```
pip install webdrivermanager

webdrivermanager chrome
```

But this gives :: `webdrivermanager: command not found`. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Pleae help

Comment: `pip show --files webdrivermanager` and see where the script is installed.

Comment: Location: /home/w*/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

```
pip list
```

What does that return?

I expect you need to restart your command prompt/terminal as it hasn't picked up the change.  Or your $PATH environment variable hasn't been amended.  Ensure webdrivermanager is accessible via the $PATH variable